# Java and UDP web server

Tags: java

I thinking of building a mini-server where Java can send data through UDP protocol so that my other Flex application can read. The data consist of short string of up to 64 characters. Should I consider HTTP instead?

Where can I find out more tutorial on building HTTP/UDP web server

Comment: Please clarify your question. 'Should I consider HTTP instead?' Impossible to say without knowing your criteria? Did you have any?

Comment: If that's a clarification it still requires clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP does not work over UDP - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp) question for details.

For information about UDP in Java, you may look at [corresponding section of standard tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html).

For simple HTTP requests via Java you may take a look at HttpUrlConnection class documentation, and at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html) section of Java tutorial.

Trivial HTTP server may be implemented with pure Java sockets. For support of wide HTTP functionality, you may take a look at [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)

Also, you may look at the [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/pkg.html) site