# Which parts of HTTP/2 are stateful?

Tags: stateful, http2

Unlike the original stateless HTTP/1, [HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) has many stateful components.

These parts of HTTP/2 are stateful:

- [Header blocks refer to a stateful unsigned 31-bit integer called a stream identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.2)
- [Frames also reference the same stateful stream identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.1.1)
- [opportunistic encryption also depends on state since TLS is stateful](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8164)

Are there any other parts of HTTP/2 that are stateful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is HTTP/2 a stateless protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178447/is-http-2-a-stateless-protocol)

Comment: @Farside This question is older.  Also, this question is asking about which components are stateful, not if the protocol is stateless.  **HTTP/2 is stateful**, and this question assumes that the reader already knows this or can reasonably infer this from the first sentence.

Comment: @Farside Also, you are the author of the current answer, which I suspect gives concern for further bias.

Comment: you are just speculating on the subject, without understanding of OSI model. HTTP/1.0 is **not** stateful. The same is fully true about HTTP/2, as application layer still remains stateless... however it does have a few stateful components according to RFC. An HTTP/2 connection is an application-layer protocol running on top of a TCP connection. Don't mix it with session and transport layers.

Comment: @Farside.  You are 50% wrong.  **HTTP/1.0 is stateless.**  No stateful mechanisms were defined by the original spec.  You are correct as you say it was stateless.  The addition of cookies add state on top of the original HTTP spec.  

**HTTP/2.0 is stateful.**  HTTP/2.0 defines new stateful mechanisms in its standard.  You don't have to use it statefully, but it's still there.

I don't know how else to communicate this to you.  This is a simple matter.  And please, don't be a jerk and say things like "without understanding of OSI model".  This is unbecoming of an Internet citizen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 2 adds many stateful components to the HTTP corpus.

- [Streams](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5) use a stateful unsigned 31-bit integer called a "stream
  identifier".
- [Header blocks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.2) are used to statefully establish the stream identifier.
- [Frames are stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4)
- [Header compression is stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.3)
- [Opportunistic encryption is stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8164)

The following are stateful components carried from previous HTTP additions which are still stateful in HTTP 2.

- [Cookies are stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109)
- [HTTPS is stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818)
- [HTTP caching is stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-13) [(See also RFC 7234.)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234)
- [HTTP defined authentication is stateful.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-11)  [(See also RFC 7235)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)
- [Web Sockets are stateful](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3) and use a stateful "Sec-WebSocket-Key" HTTP header.
- [Web Storage, although not HTTP, is also stateful.](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)