# How to do actions after return redirect?

Tags: django

I have this code:

```
size = Size.objects.get(size = 'XS')
good1.Size.remove(size)
return redirect('/')
time.sleep(600)
good1.Size.add(size)
```

So, I need to recover a model object after 10 min, but the user must be redirected to another page and be able to use another pages of the site during 10 min.

How can I do it?

Comment: This looks like a very weird "use case". Especially since it would make the webserver likely *stateful*. Stateful webservers are usually a bad idea, since the webserver can probably shut down/error at every possible moment, and start at any possible moment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is correct. See [this great topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178447/is-http-2-a-stateless-protocol) for some info

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to delegate the task of recovering the object to a background worker process using something like Celery. By making use of `task.apply_async(countdown=60 * 10)` you could redirect your user and have Celery take care of recovering the object for you.