# Accepting UDP in the Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, udp

After curiously googling about potentially accepting [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) packets in web clients (JavaScript), I was surprised to come up with almost nothing except some [articles](http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/18/google-wants-to-speed-up-the-web-with-its-quic-protocol/#.pouydl:c1SG) about [Google's experimental QUIC Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC). Here's a [recent post about it in the Chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/04/a-quic-update-on-googles-experimental.html).

My questions are as follows:

- Are there any *current* plugins/extensions/etc. that could allow browsers to accept UDP packets?
- If so, how can that be used to accept packets from a NodeJS server using the [dgram library](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html)?

With HTML5, WebGL, and web-based gaming starting to litter the internet, I thought more people would be talking about this.

I'm also curious about what the web development community as a whole thinks of QUIC, and if/when standardization of the protocol would potentially take place. Are there are any efforts besides QUIC to standardize UDP (or UDP-like) support for web clients?

Comment: Browsers (web clients) are based on HTTP.  This protocol does not support UDP.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp for more details.

Comment: Typically,an application such as a browser requires the guaranteed, in-order delivery that TCP provides, and UDP does not.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP/3 with QUIC & UDP under the hood are finally available in browsers!

- In Firefox:
  [https://hacks.mozilla.org/2021/04/quic-and-http-3-support-now-in-firefox-nightly-and-beta/](http://Enable%20HTTP/3%20in%20Firefox)
- In Chrome:
  [https://blog.chromium.org/2020/10/chrome-is-deploying-http3-and-ietf-quic.html](http://Enable%20HTTP/3%20in%20Chrome)
- In Safari:

  > Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Features > HTTP/3