# Can HTTP/HTTPS use UDP?

Tags: http, networking, https, tcp, udp

UDP is unreliable.

- No guarantee of message delivery
- No acknowledgments, retransmissions, or timeouts
- No guarantee of order of delivery
- No packet sequence numbers, no reordering, no head-of-line blocking
- No connection state tracking
- No connection establishment or teardown state machines
- No congestion control
- No built-in client or network feedback mechanisms

As far as I know, HTTP/HTTPS uses TCP.

Could HTTP/HTTPS connections also be established using UDP?

Comment: So, if the transmission is unreliable, how would a client cope with a missing packet's worth of data (say, a chunk of javascript or HTML from the resource)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does HTTP use UDP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp)

Answer (score 4):

Its being used today by google as an experimental investigation for chrome services.

Refer: http://c3lab.poliba.it/images/3/3b/QUIC_SAC15.pdf

Comment: it's not UDP, it's a reliable protocol built over UDP which is another story

Answer (score 3):

Besides HTTP, it can be used for HTTPS too, thanks to QUIC protocol, as before mentioned.

As an example: if you're aiming to block HTTPS traffic on a Linux Router with IPTABLES/Netfilter,  considering hosts that are on the LAN side, you cannot rely just on rules for dropping incoming connection with 443 as source port, considering transmission via TCP.

Take a look on this output from `conntrack` for deleting established connections:

> $ conntrack -D --orig-src 192.168.0.13
>
> **udp**      17 136 src=192.168.0.13 dst=216.58.193.14 sport=40660 dport=443 src=216.58.193.14 dst=192.168.100.1 **sport=443** dport=40660 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
>
> **udp**      17 151 src=192.168.0.13 dst=172.217.7.34 sport=46689 dport=443 src=172.217.7.34 dst=192.168.100.1 **sport=443** dport=46689 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
>
> **udp**      17 46 src=192.168.0.13 dst=216.58.193.14 sport=32995 dport=443 src=216.58.193.14 dst=192.168.100.1 **sport=443** dport=32995 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
>
> **udp**      17 55 src=192.168.0.13 dst=216.58.193.42 sport=40586 dport=443 src=216.58.193.42 dst=192.168.100.1 **sport=443** dport=40586 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1

These connections were established via UDP, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is even a special protocol for it now. DTLS.
Since you preferably want to have a stable and packets to come in order, when doing encryption you might as well do TCP. If you use UDP, you might need to resend or handle order of packets and such.