# UDP transport underneath GPRC for C# unity gaming application

Tags: unity-game-engine, udp, grpc, cronet

I am planning to use GRPC with C# and unity for gaming application. Is it possible to use UDP transport underneath GRPC? Also, is it possible to use Cronet transport underneath GRPC?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323401/7111561) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! so just to confirm it is supported for C# version as well https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/quickstart/ ? basically I am trying to develop a gaming application with C# and unity.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC has support for three transports at the current time - HTTP/2, Cronet and In-process

Refer - https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_core_transport_explainer.html