# How TCP connection handle client's total payload size

Tags: http, server, tcp

I have an HTTP server listening on a specific TCP port written in Golang. I have a logic that the server will reject the client request if the client payload is larger than a certain size.
Now I'm wondering if the total size of the user data is also negotiated in the TCP handshake or not?

Comment: TCP is only concerned with individual, ordered, packets, not application-layer operations.

Comment: Also, your question assumes HTTP uses TCP - [when in fact HTTP supports UDP just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a logic that the server will reject the client request if the client payload is larger than a certain size

I assume you're doing this by verifying the Request's `Content-Length` header against the actual aggregate data received.

> Now I'm wondering if the total size of the user data is also negotiated in the TCP handshake or not?

No, it isn't.

- First, your question assumes HTTP uses TCP - when [in fact HTTP supports UDP just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp), and [HTTP/3 uses QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) (which itself is built-on UDP).

  - And you can probably still get HTTP to run over IPX/SPX.
- TCP itself is a lower-level protocol compared to HTTP: TCP is only concerned with ensuring reliable transmission of TCP packets, and in a HTTP connection those TCP packets could contain headers, request/response content, [trailing headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer), WebSocket/SSE data, and more besides.

  - [If you were to look at the structure of TCP packet headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#:%7E:text=the%20receiving%20application.-,TCP%20segment%20structure,-%5Bedit%5D), you'll see it doesn't contain any fields for any kind of request payload length.